# drupal render file

Tags: image, drupal-7, width, render

I have images which I am rendering out

```
$filename = file_create_url($node->field_main_image['und'][0]['uri']);
print '<img src="<?php print $filename; ?>" />';
```

However this does not give me the width and height I need for IE, how do I theme with the actual  height and width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the built in rendering.

```
print render($content['field_main_image']);
```

This will output your image for you with all the heights and widths in place. You can set up image styles in the configuration page. Then in content types display you can set the image to output as one of your set image styles.

EDIT:

This only works in the node pages. If you want to do it in the page template:

```
<?='<img src="'.image_style_url('IMAGE_STYLE', $node->field_main_image['und'][$count]['filename']).'" />'?>
```

You can replace IMAGE_STYLE with the machine name of the style you want.

Comment: this only works in node? not page.tpl.php how can I access it in page.tpl.php?

Comment: this is actually wrong, cause image_style_url require and uri not the filename